# Accessing Loss without using Callback

Tags: keras

I cannot access the loss through callbacks because I'm using train_on_batch and calling it on each batch manually (this is necessary for my use).

Is there a way I can access the loss after each batch like accessing the weights of a layer with `self.model.layers[2].get_weights()[0]`?

The callback has

Answer (score 0):

The function [train_on_batch](https://keras.io/models/model/#train_on_batch) returns exactly the scalar loss of the current computed batch.

so specifically you would do

```
loss = model.train_on_batch(batch_x, batch_y)
```